# ActionScript 3.0 class extends

Tags: actionscript-3

SCENARIO:

I have the class characterObject and n class that extends (cat, dog, bird, n...)

```
public class characterObject
{
    public static var totalCounter:int;
}
public class cat extends characterObject 
public class dog extends characterObject 
public class bird extends characterObject
```

Is it possible for the extended classes to listen to changes to static variables (eg totalCounter) in the main class with or without events?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, what are you trying to do? Provide some example code if you can

Comment: @CyanAngel
Ok , I'm sorry . I have classes cat, dog, bird ( and others ... ) that extend the class characterObj. The static variable totalCounter inside characterObj is increased or decreased by a function inside classes cat, dog, bird...

Can I listen for the change value of totalCounter from cat, dog and bird concurrently? So that all know the value on change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a combination of getter/setter functions and events.

Getters and Setters, in actionscript, are functions that can be accessed like variables, giving you the ability to execute functions on variable changes.

```
public class characterObject
{
    private static var _totalCounter:int;
    protected static var internalDispatcher:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    public static function get totalCounter():int
    {
        return _totalCounter;
    }
    public static function set totalCounter(value:int):void
    {
        _totalCounter = value;
        var event:Event = new Event("totalCounterChanged");
        internalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

As you can see we have a `protected static` event dispatcher called `internalDispatcher`, we can listen to events from this object only if we have extended the `characterObject` class. By hiding the true `totalCounter` behind the getter/setter we can dispatch an event whenever something changes it's value.

We can then listen for this event in our extended classes:

```
public class cat extends characterObject
{
    public function cat()
    {
        super();
        internalDispatcher.addEventListener("totalCounterChanged",totalChangedHandler);
    }
    public function totalChangedHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        //Your code here;
    }
}
```

Depending on your requirements it maybe better to have your Event Handlers be static also to reduce the same code being executed multiple times without a change in output.